# Problem with layout of new elements added in the grid

Tags: css, grid

I have these requirements:

1. At the start I have such elements as: *info, description, gallery, amenities, important, sidebar* - in the div with class: *details*.
2. All items except sidebar are on the left, sidebar on the right.

**And I can't achieve it:**

**Newly added elements, eg. a div with class *test* should always be on the left side - the number of new elements is incalculable. - at the moment, an element is added to the left column once and to the right column once, and this is an wrong for me.**

**How is (wrong):**

[image]

**How would I like? (note that the tests are below each other in the left column)**

[image]

Why such a structure? because on the mobile sidebar it can be above or below any element on the left side.

Codepen:
[link to snippet](https://codepen.io/kuci123/pen/wvQKopZ)

HTML:

```
<section class="l-section l-section--details">
 <div class="l-wrapper">
   <div class="details">
     <div class="details__info">info</div>
     <div class="details__description">lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test </div>
     <div class="details__gallery">gallery</div>
     <div class="details__amenities">amenities</div>
     <div class="details__important">important</div>
     <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
     <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
     <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
     <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
     <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
     <div class="details__sidebar">
       <div class="details__sidebar-content">
         <div class="details__sidebar-price">sidebar content price</div>
         <div class="details__sidebar-buttons">sidebar content buttons</div>
         <div class="details__sidebar-icons">sidebar content icons</div>
         <div class="details__sidebar-more">sidebar content more sidebar content more</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
</section>

<section class="l-section l-section--details-others">
 <div class="l-wrapper">
   <div class="details-others">
     details others
   </div> 
 </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 width: 500px;
 border: 3px solid black;
}

.l-section--details {
 margin: auto;
 margin: 30px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.l-section--details-others {
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.details {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 0.7fr 0.3fr;
 grid-template-rows: auto auto;
 grid-auto-rows: min-content; /* OR min-content*/
 gap: 0 100px;
 
 grid-template-areas:
   "info sidebar"
   "description sidebar"
   "gallery sidebar"
   "amenities sidebar"
   "important sidebar";
 
 & > * {
   padding: 2px;
   margin: 10px;
 }
   
 &__info {
   background: red;
   grid-area: info;
 }
 
 &__description {
   background: green;
   grid-area: description;
 }
 
 &__gallery {
   background: blue;
   grid-area: gallery;
 }
 
 &__amenities {
   background: orange;
   grid-area: amenities;
 }
 
 &__important {
   background: purple;
   grid-area: important;
 }
 
 &__sidebar {
   position: relative;
   grid-area: sidebar;
   align-items: start;
 }
 
 &__sidebar-content {
   position: sticky;
   top: 30px;
   align-items: start;
   background: gold;
 }
 
 &__test {
   width: 100%;
 }
 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 .details {
    grid-template-areas:
   "sidebar sidebar"
   "info info"  
   "description description"
   "gallery gallery"
   "amenities amenities"
   "important important";
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand! Could you put an image of what you intend to achieve? Or 2 images: 1 desktop, 1 mobile

Comment: @pierfarrugia I have added pictures of what is with and what I would like to achieve. Generally, the idea is that newly added sections go to the left column.

Answer (score 0):

I simplify your structure, I don't know up to what point you can do it, but this snippet seems to answer your question. Test it in portrait / landscape

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.l-section--details {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 25%;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 30px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.l-section--details-others {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="l-section l-section--details">
  <div class="detailsWrapper">
    <div class="details__info">info</div>
    <div class="details__description">lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem
      test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test
      lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem ipsum lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem
      dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test lorem dorum lorem test</div>
    <div class="details__gallery">gallery</div>
    <div class="details__amenities">amenities</div>
    <div class="details__important">important</div>
    <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
    <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
    <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
    <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
    <div class="details__test">test 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="details__sidebar">
    <div class="details__sidebar-content">
      <div class="details__sidebar-price">sidebar content price</div>
      <div class="details__sidebar-buttons">sidebar content buttons</div>
      <div class="details__sidebar-icons">sidebar content icons</div>
      <div class="details__sidebar-more">sidebar content more sidebar content more</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="l-section l-section--details-others">
  <div class="l-wrapper">
    <div class="details-others">
      details others
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you added the detailsWrapper element - and this removes the possibility of giving a sidebar, e.g. between gallery and amenities on MOBILE.

Comment: As said I don't see exactly what you intend to achieve! Do you want several parts with each one 1 sidebar? Some of them with sidebar? only 1 sidebar?

Comment: In general, the point is that we have two sides - left and right. On the left there will always be large components (any number) On the right there will always be ONLY ONE SIDEBAR.

The thing is:
1. There can be any number of elements in the left column - that is, when I add a new DIV, it should always fall into the left column.
2. On Mobile - the sidebar can be between any section on the left side..